# VideoJS buggy in Safari when using Twitter Bootstrap Panes

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, video.js

I am using Twitter Bootstrap Tab-able Panes with each pane on my site. Each pane has a video.js video embedded on it.

Everything works fine on all major browsers except the latest version of Safari (I'm using Windows).

There are two problems in Safari:

1. The Video.js controls do not show unless you resize the browser
   window. Once you do this, it's fine. NOTE: This is NOT a problem
   when I embed the code straight into a page - it's only a problem
   when put into a TBS pane.
2. If I have multiple videos (in panes) on a page, it seems there is
   some limit. Once I reach it (sometimes 2/3, sometimes 6), the audio
   plays, but either (a) the video is 'blank'/black or (b) the video is
   stuck on a single frame.

Highly frustrating :) ANY ideas or solutions appreciated.

Example URL: http://kickstart3d.com.au/learn/category/kickstart-leadership/induction/

Example embed code:

```
<div id='pane-k3d-424' class='tab-pane active'>
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
        <video id="my_video_721961889" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="http://www.liveyourown.com/video/k3d-video_starthere.jpg" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="http://www.liveyourown.com/video/k3d-induction-intro.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```